# How to change "-1" and "0" in checkbox field filter dialog in Spreadsheet View when it's based on a calculated field (MS Access)?

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, spreadsheet

In my MS Access table I have a Calculated field that returns True or False.
Then I use it in my form in Spreadsheet View as a Checkbox.
The filter dialog for this field shows "-1" and "0" as filtering options. It's not friendly for the user. How to change it?

[Checkbox filter dialog for a Calculated field in Spreadsheet View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDTzS.png)

I tried to use a calculated field right in the Spreadsheet Form, but filtering of Calculated Fields is not supported in Spreadsheet Forms.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: You can't. But you could use a query as source where you have an expression: Format([YourField], "Yes/No").

Comment: I have the following query. Could you, please, tell me where do I have to paste this line? (I'm absolutely noob there.)

`SELECT Staff.*, contact.*, IIf(Staff.[DOB] Is Not Null, DateDiff("yyyy",Staff.[DOB],Date()),"") AS Age
FROM Staff LEFT JOIN contact ON Staff.ID = contact.id
WHERE ((contact.po)>Date() OR isnull(contact.po))
ORDER BY Staff.ID;`

Comment: Yes, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```sql
SELECT 
    Staff.*, 
    contact.*, 
    IIf(Staff.[DOB] Is Not Null, DateDiff("yyyy",Staff.[DOB],Date()),"") AS Age,
    Format([YourCheckboxField], "Yes/No") As FriendlyCheckboxName
FROM 
    Staff 
LEFT JOIN 
    contact 
    ON Staff.ID = contact.id 
WHERE 
    ((contact.po) > Date() OR isnull(contact.po)) 
ORDER BY 
    Staff.ID;
```

[image: Yes/No]

Or force the labels:

```sql
SELECT 
    Staff.*, 
    contact.*, 
    IIf(Staff.[DOB] Is Not Null, DateDiff("yyyy",Staff.[DOB],Date()),"") AS Age,
    IIf([YourCheckboxField], "Так", "Ні") As FriendlyCheckboxName
```

[image]

Comment: I've got another layer for my question. The users have their Access in different languages. In this case "Yes/No" is not recognized as checkbox states and they get "semi-selected" checkboxes in the form. I tried to change "Yes/No" to "True/False" but it didn't help. Is there any localisation-independent option to use instead of "Yes/No"?

Comment: `Yes/No` as shown in SQL will be localised. See screenshot in Danish.

Comment: Maybe, it just doesn't work with Ukrainian for some reason.

Comment: It does, but your screenshot is in English, not Ukrainian.